# Make sure a forEach with async calls is executed before another one?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a function with multiple `forEach` loops:

```
async insertKpbDocument(jsonFile) {
    jsonFile.doc.annotations.forEach((annotation) => {
      annotation.entities.forEach(async (entity) => {
        await this.addVertex(entity);
      });
      annotation.relations.forEach(async (relation) => {
        await this.addRelation(relation);
      });
    });
    return jsonFile;
  }
```

I need to make sure that the async code in the `forEach` loop calling the `this.addVertex` function is really done before executing the next one.

But when I log variables, It seems that the `this.addRelation` function is called before the first loop is really over.

So I tried adding `await` terms before every loops like so :

```
await jsonFile.doc.annotations.forEach(async (annotation) => {
      await annotation.entities.forEach(async (entity) => {
        await this.addVertex(entity);
      });
      await annotation.relations.forEach(async (relation) => {
        await this.addRelation(relation);
      });
    });
```

But same behavior.

Maybe it is the log function that have a latency? Any ideas?

Comment: You can't write `async` code as you would do with synchronous code, just adding `async`/`await` keywords. What exactly do you want to be `async`? Why sync calls or callbacks do not work to sequence your `addVertex` and `addRelation`??

Comment: well, before adding Relations, I need to add all the Vertices. @RaphaMex

Comment: Use an actual `for` loop instead of  `.forEach()` loop and the `await` will actually pause the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 My lint doesn't allow me to use `for` loops ... ahah

Comment: Then, get a new lint.  That's ridiculous that you can't use a `for` loop.  `await` only pauses the closest scope function and then immediately returns a promise from that function.  With `.forEach()`, the closest scope function is your callback.  So your callback is paused, but it immediately returns a promise and the parent `.forEach()` keeps running, unpaused.  With a `for` loop, the closest scope function is your entire function which is what you want.

Comment: @jfriend00 I use the airbnb lint. They say : "You need to use things like map/every/some/filter/reduce/find/findIndex etc to iterate over arrays, and Object.keys/Object.values/Object.entries to produce arrays so you can iterate over objects." for loops aren't a best practice. You can look at the answer, it uses map!

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud - That's the STUPIDEST lint restriction I've ever heard of.  The `for/of` construct is extremely efficient and useful and a `for` loop is extremely useful with `await`.  Your code would be so much simpler, than even the answer you accepted.  Just because it can be done does not mean it's the best way to write things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we've discussed, `await` does not pause a `.forEach()` loop and does not make the 2nd item of the iteration wait for the first item to be processed.  So, if you're really trying to do asynchronous sequencing of items, you can't really accomplish it with a `.forEach()` loop.

For this type of problem, `async/await` works really well with a plain `for` loop because they do pause the execution of the actual `for` statement to give you sequencing of asynchronous operations which it appears is what you want.  Plus, it even works with nested `for` loops because they are all in the same function scope:

To show you how much simpler this can be using `for/of` and `await`, it could be done like this:

```
async insertKpbDocument(jsonFile) {
    for (let annotation of jsonFile.doc.annotations) {
        for (let entity of annotation.entities) {
            await this.addVertex(entity);
        }
        for (let relation of annotation.relations) {
            await this.addRelation(relation);
        }
    }
    return jsonFile;
}
```

You get to write synchronous-like code that is actually sequencing asynchronous operations.

---

If you are really avoiding any `for` loop, and your real requirement is only that all calls to `addVertex()` come before any calls to `addRelation()`, then you can do this where you use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` and you collect an array of promises that you then use `Promise.all()` to wait on the whole array of promises:

```
insertKpbDocument(jsonFile) {
    return Promise.all(jsonFile.doc.annotations.map(async annotation => {
        await Promise.all(annotation.entities.map(entity => this.addVertex(entity)));
        await Promise.all(annotation.relations.map(relation => this.addRelation(relation)));
    })).then(() => jsonFile);
}
```

To fully understand how this works, this runs all `addVertex()` calls in parallel for one annotation, waits for them all to finish, then runs all the `addRelation()` calls in parallel for one annotation, then waits for them all to finish.  It runs all the annotations themselves in parallel.  So, this isn't very much actual sequencing except within an annotation, but you accepted an answer that has this same sequencing and said it works so I show a little simpler version of this for completeness.

---

If you really need to sequence each individual `addVertex()` call so you don't call the next one until the previous one is done and you're still not going to use a `for` loop, then you can use the `.reduce()` promise pattern put into a helper function to manually sequence asynchronous access to an array:

```
// helper function to sequence asynchronous iteration of an array
// fn returns a promise and is passed an array item as an argument
function sequence(array, fn) {
    return array.reduce((p, item) => {
        return p.then(() => {
            return fn(item);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}


insertKpbDocument(jsonFile) {
    return sequence(jsonFile.doc.annotations, async (annotation) => {
        await sequence(annotation.entities, entity => this.addVertex(entity));
        await sequence(annotation.relations, relation => this.addRelation(relation));
    }).then(() => jsonFile);
}
```

This will completely sequence everything.  It will do this type of order:

```
addVertex(annotation1)
addRelation(relation1);
addVertex(annotation2)
addRelation(relation2);
....
addVertex(annotationN);
addRelation(relationN);
```

where it waits for each operation to finish before going onto the next one.

Answer (score 5):

`foreach` will return `void` so awaiting it will not do much. You can use `map` to return all the promises you create now in the `forEach`, and use `Promise.all` to await all:

```
async insertKpbDocument(jsonFile: { doc: { annotations: Array<{ entities: Array<{}>, relations: Array<{}> }> } }) {
    await Promise.all(jsonFile.doc.annotations.map(async(annotation) => {
        await Promise.all(annotation.entities.map(async (entity) => {
            await this.addVertex(entity);
        }));
        await Promise.all(annotation.relations.map(async (relation) => {
            await this.addRelation(relation);
        }));
    }));
    return jsonFile;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: `await jsonFile.doc.annotations.map()` is wrong.  `.map()` returns an array so you are awaiting an array, not a promise.  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you do `await Promise.all`, there's no reason to `await` within the `this.addVertex` and `this.addRelation`. You can direclty return the  promise.

Comment: The OP said ***"I need to make sure that the async code in the forEach loop calling the this.addVertex function is really done before executing the next one."***.  I don't see how this code accomplishes that.  Just like with `.forEach()`, `.map()` won't pause the looping just because you did an `await` inside the `.map()` callback.  So, this isn't serializing all the calls to `this.addVertex()`.  It's running several in a parallel which is not what the OP said they needed.

Comment: Similarly, there's no reason for `await this.addRelation(relation)` either.  Just do `return this.addRelation(relation)`.

Comment: For me it isn't clear what OP wants to happen in sequence: does every `addVertix` need to happen in sequence? Or does every `addVertix` need to happen (in any order) before all the `addRelation` calls? And does the `addRelation` order matter? This answer is at least the right direction... :)

Comment: Every `addVertex` need to happen in any order as well as `addRelation`. So which `await` are obsoletes?

Comment: Then I say this answer is spot on. The 2nd and 3rd `await`s (in reading order) solve the problem as stated, the rest just ensure the entire function resolves after its all done (which is different than your original function and not something you specifically requested, but probably a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

I understand you can run all the addVertex concurrently. Combining reduce with map splitted into two different set of promises you can do it. My idea:

```
const first = jsonFile.doc.annotations.reduce((acc, annotation) => {
  acc = acc.concat(annotation.entities.map(this.addVertex));

  return acc;
}, []);

await Promise.all(first);

const second = jsonFile.doc.annotations.reduce((acc, annotation) => {
  acc = acc.concat(annotation.relations.map(this.addRelation));

  return acc;
}, []);

await Promise.all(second);
```

You have more loops, but it does what you need I think

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` does not within `forEach`.

A simple solution: Replace `.forEach()` with `for(.. of ..)` instead.

Details in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

If `no-iterator` linting rule is enabled, you will get a linting warning/error for using `for(.. of ..)`. There are lots of [discussion/opinions](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1122) on this topic.

IMHO, this is a scenario where we can suppress the warning with [eslint-disable-next-line](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) or for the method/class.

Example:

```
const insertKpbDocument = async (jsonFile) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-iterator
  for (let entity of annotation.entities) {
    await this.addVertex(entity)
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-iterator
  for (let relation of annotation.relations) {
    await this.addRelation(relation)
  }
  return jsonFile
}
```

The code is very **readable** and works as expected. To get similar functionality with `.forEach()`, we need some promises/observables acrobatics that i think is a waste of effort.

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud A linter is a tool to help you not to prevent you from working. In this case, change the linting ruleset.

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud i've updated the answer with a link a long conversation where people faced this same issue. Lots of 'opinions' there...hehe.. i am just sharing mine as well. :-) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` executes the callback against each element in the array and does not wait for anything. Using `await` is basically sugar for writing `promise.then()` and nesting everything that follows in the `then()` callback. But `forEach` doesn't return a promise, so `await arr.forEach()` is meaningless. The only reason it isn't a compile error is because the async/await spec says you can `await` anything, and if it isn't a promise you just get its value... `forEach` just gives you `void`.

If you want something to happen in sequence you can `await` in a `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < jsonFile.doc.annotations.length; i++) {
  const annotation = jsonFile.doc.annotations[i]; 
  for (let j = 0; j < annotation.entities.length; j++) {
    const entity = annotation.entities[j];
    await this.addVertex(entity);
  });
  // code here executes after all vertix have been added in order
```

**Edit:** While typing this a couple other answers and comments happened... you don't want to use a `for` loop, you can use `Promise.all` but there's still maybe some confusion, so I'll leave the above explanation in case it helps.