# nodejs Await promises working but log shows different order

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm self taught in NodeJS and have created a process of:

- Finding 'claims' requiring an invoice (return array)
- For each claim in the array, create an invoice
- After invoice is created update a table ([scripts]) based on the claimID.

Now the code is working and I believe the Async/Await is working so that the invoices are created and attached in the correct order as so far my tests show this is correct.

What I am curious about is:

- Would this be better phrased as using .THEN or is what I have "acceptable"
- Why is my console.log showing the claimID's processed in a different order than the array?

The main section in question is the FOREACH section.

My log is as below:

> ```
> [
>   RowDataPacket { ClaimID: 2457 },
>   RowDataPacket { ClaimID: 1370 },
>   RowDataPacket { ClaimID: 1 },
>   RowDataPacket { ClaimID: 1853 },
>   RowDataPacket { ClaimID: 2438 }
> ]
> 2457
> 1370
> 1
> 1853
> 2438
> Attached invoice 23393 For Claim 2457
> Attached invoice 23395 For Claim 1
> Attached invoice 23394 For Claim 1370
> Attached invoice 23397 For Claim 2438
> Attached invoice 23396 For Claim 1853
> ```

If the array is in order, then the claimID log number is in order,
WHY are the logs for the "invoice created" out of order in Function[createInvoiceAndAttach]?

This doesn't affect my end result, I'm I just want to understand the whole async situation better!

```
router.post('/generateInvoices/',verify, async (req,res) => {    
    const uploadBody = req.body;
    
    
    const ScrBatchID = uploadBody.ScrBatchID;
    const scriptList = uploadBody.zephyrScripts;
    const invBatchDate = uploadBody.scriptBatchDate;
    
   
    try{
        //Update prices etc on the script table.
        // This function also checks a few other components returning true/false depending on success of the update.
        const updateScriptsSuccess = await updateScripts(scriptList);

        if(!updateScriptsSuccess){
            return res.status(200).json({
                
                Result: false
                
            })  
        }

        //Create an Invoice BATCH - related to todays dateTime.
        const invoiceBatchID = await createInvoiceBatch(invBatchDate,req.user._id);
        console.log(invoiceBatchID);


        //Get an array of the claim ID's
        const claimsToInvoice = await getClaimsToInvoice(ScrBatchID);
        console.log(claimsToInvoice);


        let invoiceUpdateSuccess = false;   

        //For each of the Claim ID's in the array, Create an invoice ID using the invoiceBatchID previously obtained
        //In the subfunction, also add this obtained InvoiceID to the script table
        claimsToInvoice.forEach(async (claim) => {
            let ClaimID = claim.ClaimID;
            console.log(ClaimID);
            invoiceUpdateSuccess = await createInvoiceAndAttach(invoiceBatchID,ClaimID, ScrBatchID);
            
            
            //Return the result of the update.  If any of the subfunctions errored out, they will filter up a FALSE and thus the total success is false.
            if(!invoiceUpdateSuccess){
                return res.status(200).json({
                
                    Result: false
                    
                })  
            } 



        })
        
            
        //If nothing above failed, continue to this section and mark this batch of claims as completed, so they don't get invoiced again.
        const totalSuccess = await updateScriptBatch(ScrBatchID,invBatchDate,req.user._id);

        if(totalSuccess){
            return res.status(200).json({
            
                Result: true
                
            })  
        }else{
            return res.status(200).json({
                
                Result: false
                
            }) 
        }
    }catch (e) {
        // this catches any exception in this scope or await rejection
        console.log(e);
        
        return res.status(500).json({
                
            Result: false
            
        }) 
    } 
});

function createInvoiceAndAttach(invoiceBatchID,ClaimID, ScrBatchID){
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) =>{     
        
        
        let InvoiceID = await getInvoiceID(invoiceBatchID);
        //console.log(InvBatchDate);
        if(InvoiceID == 0){
            return reject(false);
        }else{

            try{
            
                //console.log(scriptID + " " + invAmount);
                var sqlString = "SET @InvoiceID = ?; SET @ScrBatchID = ?; SET @ClaimID = ?; Call updateScriptWithInvoiceID(@InvoiceID,@ScrBatchID,@ClaimID);";
                
                connection.query(sqlString,[InvoiceID,ScrBatchID,ClaimID], (err,rows,fields)=>{
                    
                    if(!err){
                        console.log("Attached invoice " + InvoiceID + " For Claim " + ClaimID);
                        return resolve(true);  
        
                    }else{
                        return reject(false);
                    } 
                        
                })
            } catch (e) {
                // this catches any exception in this scope or await rejection
                console.log(e);
                
                return reject(false);
            } 

        }

        
        
    }) 
    
};

function getInvoiceID(InvoiceBatchID){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{     
        
        

        //console.log(InvBatchDate);
        

        try{
            
            //console.log(scriptID + " " + invAmount);
            var sqlString = "INSERT INTO invoices(InvoiceBatchID) VALUES (?);";
            
            connection.query(sqlString,[InvoiceBatchID], (err,rows,fields)=>{
                
                if(!err){
                    
                    return resolve(rows.insertId);  
    
                }else{
                    return reject(0);
                } 
                    
            })
        } catch (e) {
            // this catches any exception in this scope or await rejection
            console.log(e);
            
            return reject(0);
        } 
        
    })   
};
```

Comment: As described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101875/make-sure-a-foreach-with-async-calls-is-executed-before-another-one/50110131#50110131) your question is marked a duplicate of, `.forEach()` is not promise-aware at all.  So, when you give it an `async` callback and use `await` in that callback, the `.forEach()` loop does not wait for the `await`.  Instead, it just starts the next iteration of the loop and all the iterations end up running in parallel with random finish order.  Get rid of `.forEach()` for all asynchronous programming.  Use a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 . I had a feeling there was something 'basic' i was missing.